# How to get systemd-resolved to use /etc/hosts when openFortiVPN is active

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, systemd-resolved

Ubuntu 18.04.   I have a host entry in /etc/hosts and this is being resolved correctly when I use *nslookup*.  My /etc/nsswitch.conf looks like

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files [SUCCESS=return] mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

/etc/resolv.conf looks like

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

When I start connect to the VPN this changes to

```
nameserver 172.16.1.46
nameserver 172.16.1.47
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

options edns0
```

Unfortunately these name severs have a different value for the host entry that I entered into `/etc/hosts` and resolving is not using the entry in `/etc/hosts` any more. It is definitely VPN related as when I tear down the VPN, it once again resolves to the entry in `/etc/hosts`

What I would like to do is to somehow force `/etc/hosts` to be the first place entries are resolved, but I have found no way to do so as of yet.